# What are the dimensions of ship tokens in ship on ship combat, via GoS, suppose to be?

Tags: dnd-5e, battle-map, vehicles, ghosts-of-saltmarsh, tokens

I've had some conflicting information on whether a gargantuan ship from Ghosts of Saltmarsh is suppose to have a 20x20 token or an accurately dimensioned token, when used in ship v ship combat. For me and my players, this is an important distinction for usefulness of certain spells like Fog Cloud, or location aboard the ship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Gargantuan is 20 by 20 ft. *or larger*

In the rules for creature size, there is a table that tells you the dimensions for each size category, and gargantuan says:

> 20 by 20 ft. **or larger**

So their actual size is not restricted by their size category, since gargantuan is 20x20 *and every size beyond.*

It should be noted that the ship rules actually bend this general rule a bit:

> Most ships are Large, Huge, or Gargantuan. A ship’s size category is determined by its length or width, whichever is longer. For instance, a ship that is 10 feet long and 20 feet wide would use the size category that has a 20-foot width, which means the ship is Gargantuan.

So a ship’s size category is determined by its longest dimension only.

#### The ship’s stat block lists its dimensions.

Use the dimensions of the ship listed in the ship’s description. For example, the galley is listed as:

> Gargantuan vehicle **(130 ft. by 20 ft.)**

So a galley token would be 26x4 squares.

Comment: What sort of ship is wider than it is long?

Comment: Ive got a follow up question then, if you wouldn't mind. If that is the case, then would creatures follow a similar logic? Like the Purple Worm, its notably longer than it is wide or tall. So should it also be given a token that expresses that fact, or is this more of a rule for vehicles?

Comment: RAW? it is not.... My group however has large, huge, gargantuan etc... creatures take up the space they take up... it is more fun.